# problem installing orocos_toolchain from source

Tags: ros, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use orocos_toolchain to control a multi link robot in real time, but when i try to install the orocos_toolchain package from source, i get the above error:`Failed to process package 'utilrb'`
, what is the problem?  I followed [this link](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration/blob/hydro-devel/README.md) to install it.
I also tried this [ros tutorial:](http://wiki.ros.org/orocos_toolchain) but i get the error:

```
 Could not resolve host: git.gitorious.org
```

this same error was also coming when i followed first link but after i changed git wit http it worked, but in the second link, i dont know what is the problem. So how do i install orocos with ros ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254291/problem-installing-orocos_toolchain-from-source/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a reason why you want to build the orocos_toolchain from source, if you're using indigo on Ubuntu you can use the binary packages instead.

Otherwise, can you try this updated documentation instead: https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/orocos_toolchain/blob/installation-script/INSTALL.md

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2017-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2017-02-10**:
thank u, well i want to control the robot in real time so that is why i wanted to learn it.